# How to persist state across pages using NextJS and useContext hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-hooks, next.js

My app is running on NextJS and I would like for some list items that users generate on my index.js page to stay in state for whenever a user hits my results.js page via a `<Link>`. I decided that I could use the `useContext` hook to keep track of state at a global level, yet the problem I am having is that the NextJS app seems to be refreshing itself every time I make a page change which render's my list array blank. Below are the 4 main pieces of code I created that should be accomplishing the persisted state:

Here I created a custom `_app.js` to wrap my pages with the `ItemContext` state by using `.Provider` and adding the values from another component I created called `useItemState` to handle the item handlers and items themselves.

```js
// _app.js

import useItemState from '../components/useItemState';
import ItemContext from '../components/ItemContext';

function MyApp({Component, pageProps}){
    const { items, addItem, deleteItem, updateItem  } = useItemState([]);

    return (
    <ItemContext.Provider value={{items, addItem, deleteItem, updateItem}}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ItemContext.Provider>
    )
}

  export default MyApp;
```

This is the ItemContext component which houses the initial `createContext`

```js
// ItemContext.js

const ItemContext = createContext(null)

export default ItemContext
```

In Index.js, Im calling the items and item handlers from my `ItemContext` file which now has access to all of these functions since I wrapped this page with the values from my custom _app.js file. At the end of this file I have a `<Link>` to the `results.js` page that ***should*** pass along the `items` values generated in this file.

```js
// index.js

export default function Index() {
  const { items, addItem, deleteItem, updateItem } = useContext(ItemContext)

// ...misc code here... //

return (
    <Layout>
// ...misc code here... //

      <ItemContext.Provider value={items}>
        <Link href='/results'>
          <a>Click Me</a>
        </Link>
      </ItemContext.Provider>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

In the results.js page I'm referencing the `items` from ItemContext yet when my app hits this page, NextJS refreshes it and I lose my items.

```js
// results.js

export default function Results() {
    const { items } = useContext(ItemContext)
    return (
    <Layout>
        {items}
    <Link href='/'> Home </Link>
    </Layout>
    );
}
```

As stated before, Im not sure how to prevent NextJS from refreshing the app on page changes to persist my state. From the NextJS docs regarding [custom app](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) it clearly states that this is a feature that is possible: Keeping state when navigating pages

Im unsure if I am not using the correct form of routing by using the  component or if my `useContext` logic is messed up. I know my context is for sure working because my index.js page works appropriately and I can log the items to the console on my results page for a split second right before the app refreshes itself and they are erased. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No need to use the context provider in pages as you already have it in _app, so you can remove `ItemContext.Provider` from index.js

Comment: Yes you basically provide the items twice. All you need is to provide it from the parent component to ALL children nodes and access it via `useContext`